# Compute divergence of vector field using python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Is there a function that could be used for calculation of the divergence of the vectorial field? (in [matlab](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/techdoc/ref/divergence.html)) I would expect it exists in numpy/scipy but I can not find it using Google.

I need to calculate `div[A * grad(F)]`, where

```
F = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]) # (2D numpy ndarray)

A = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]) # (2D numpy ndarray)
```

so `grad(F)` is a list of 2D `ndarray`s

I know I can calculate divergence like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence#Application_in_Cartesian_coordinates) but do not want to reinvent the wheel. (I would also expect something more optimized) Does anyone have suggestions?

Comment: What order accuracy do you need?  are your arrays equally spaced?

Comment: http://blog.sun.tc/2010/10/jensenshannon-divergence-in-numpy.html

Comment: @mgilson Yes, arrays are equally spaced. I need double precision.

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry, Jensen–Shannon divergence is something completely different

Comment: @nyvltak -- Not precision, order.  As in `O(h)` or `O(h**2)`, and what is the spacing? ...

Comment: @nyvltak thank you. I will read about this kind of divergence. But could you briefly explain me the main differences?

Comment: Correct way to do it, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67970477/compute-divergence-with-python/67971515#67971515

Answer (score 25):

Just a hint for everybody reading that:

the functions above do not compute the divergence of a vector field. they sum the derivatives of a scalar field A:

**result = dA/dx + dA/dy**

in contrast to a vector field (with three dimensional example):

**result = sum dAi/dxi = dAx/dx + dAy/dy + dAz/dz**

Vote down for all! It is mathematically simply wrong.

Cheers!

Comment: Kind of weird how this is at the bottom of the page. The other answers are really mathematically incorrect

Comment: This may be mathematically correct, but is only a first step towards an answer. The current text does not answer the question. There are updated answers below that actually answers the question at hand.

Comment: This answer could be improved by also telling me the answer to the question I googled, as well as telling me the other answers here are not what I want.

Comment: Here is the correct way of doing it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67970477/compute-divergence-with-python/67971515#67971515

Comment: What??? The Matlab function linked above does indeed calculate the divergence of a vector field. What is that you're referring to, here? It makes no sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 12):

```
import numpy as np

def divergence(field):
    "return the divergence of a n-D field"
    return np.sum(np.gradient(field),axis=0)
```

Comment: `field` is a *scalar field*. This does not compute the divergence of a *vector field*.

Answer (score 12):

Based on Juh_'s answer, but modified for the correct divergence of a vector field formula

```
def divergence(f):
    """
    Computes the divergence of the vector field f, corresponding to dFx/dx + dFy/dy + ...
    :param f: List of ndarrays, where every item of the list is one dimension of the vector field
    :return: Single ndarray of the same shape as each of the items in f, which corresponds to a scalar field
    """
    num_dims = len(f)
    return np.ufunc.reduce(np.add, [np.gradient(f[i], axis=i) for i in range(num_dims)])
```

[Matlab's documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/divergence.html) uses this exact formula (scroll down to Divergence of a Vector Field)

Answer (score 11):

The answer of @user2818943 is good, but it can be optimized a little:

```
def divergence(F):
    """ compute the divergence of n-D scalar field `F` """
    return reduce(np.add,np.gradient(F))
```

---

Timeit:

```
F = np.random.rand(100,100)
timeit reduce(np.add,np.gradient(F))
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 318 us per loop

timeit np.sum(np.gradient(F),axis=0)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 2.27 ms per loop
```

About 7 times faster: 
`sum` implicitely construct a 3d array from the list of gradient fields which are returned by `np.gradient`. This is avoided using `reduce`

---

Now, in your question what do you mean by  `div[A * grad(F)]`?

1. about `A * grad(F)`: `A` is a 2d array, and `grad(f)` is a list of 2d arrays. So I considered it means to multiply each gradient field by `A`.
2. about applying divergence to the (scaled by `A`) gradient field is unclear. By definition, `div(F) = d(F)/dx + d(F)/dy + ...`. I guess this is just an error of formulation.

For `1`, multiplying summed elements `Bi` by a same factor `A` can be factorized:

```
Sum(A*Bi) = A*Sum(Bi)
```

Thus, you can get this weighted gradient simply with: `A*divergence(F)`

If ̀`A` is instead a list of factor, one for each dimension, then the solution would be:

```
def weighted_divergence(W,F):
    """
    Return the divergence of n-D array `F` with gradient weighted by `W`

    ̀`W` is a list of factors for each dimension of F: the gradient of `F` over
    the `i`th dimension is multiplied by `W[i]`. Each `W[i]` can be a scalar
    or an array with same (or broadcastable) shape as `F`.
    """
    wGrad = return map(np.multiply, W, np.gradient(F))
    return reduce(np.add,wGrad)

result = weighted_divergence(A,F)
```

Comment: Isn't the divergence of a vector field F = d(Fx)/dx + d(Fy)/dy + ... ?
The correct formula would be something more like `np.ufunc.reduce(np.add, [np.gradient(F[i], axis=i) for i in range(len(F))])`

Comment: That all depends on the type of data in F. The question is unclear. I have experience in image processing, thus I consider F to be a nD image, and thus the gradient is the derivative*s* by _axis_ x then y (and more if there are). Which I sum up. If I understand correctly, if F is a n*m 2D sequence of n vector that are m-dimensional, then I guess your formulation is the correct one. HOwever, I would not understand it if F is more than 2d

Answer (score 6):

What Daniel had modified is the right answer, let me explain self defined func divergence further in more detail :

Function `np.gradient()` defined as : `np.gradient(f)` = df/dx, df/dy, df/dz +...

but we need define func divergence as : divergence ( f) = dfx/dx + dfy/dy + dfz/dz +... = `np.gradient( fx)` + `np.gradient(fy)` + `np.gradient(fz)` + ...

Let's test, compare with [example of divergence in matlab](http://www2.math.umd.edu/%7Epetersd/241/html/ex27b.html#1)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

NY = 50
ymin = -2.
ymax = 2.
dy = (ymax -ymin )/(NY-1.)

NX = NY
xmin = -2.
xmax = 2.
dx = (xmax -xmin)/(NX-1.)

def divergence(f):
    num_dims = len(f)
    return np.ufunc.reduce(np.add, [np.gradient(f[i], axis=i) for i in range(num_dims)])

y = np.array([ ymin + float(i)*dy for i in range(NY)])
x = np.array([ xmin + float(i)*dx for i in range(NX)])

x, y = np.meshgrid( x, y, indexing = 'ij', sparse = False)

Fx  = np.cos(x + 2*y)
Fy  = np.sin(x - 2*y)

F = [Fx, Fy]
g = divergence(F)

plt.pcolormesh(x, y, g)
plt.colorbar()
plt.savefig( 'Div' + str(NY) +'.png', format = 'png')
plt.show()
```

[image]

**---------- UPDATED VERSION: Include the differential Steps----------------**

Thank the comment from @henry, the `np.gradient` take the default step as 1, so the results may have some mismatch. We can provide our own differential steps.

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/47905007/5845212
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

NY = 50
ymin = -2.
ymax = 2.
dy = (ymax -ymin )/(NY-1.)

NX = NY
xmin = -2.
xmax = 2.
dx = (xmax -xmin)/(NX-1.)


def divergence(f,h):
    """
    div(F) = dFx/dx + dFy/dy + ...
    g = np.gradient(Fx,dx, axis=1)+ np.gradient(Fy,dy, axis=0) #2D
    g = np.gradient(Fx,dx, axis=2)+ np.gradient(Fy,dy, axis=1) +np.gradient(Fz,dz,axis=0) #3D
    """
    num_dims = len(f)
    return np.ufunc.reduce(np.add, [np.gradient(f[i], h[i], axis=i) for i in range(num_dims)])

y = np.array([ ymin + float(i)*dy for i in range(NY)])
x = np.array([ xmin + float(i)*dx for i in range(NX)])

x, y = np.meshgrid( x, y, indexing = 'ij', sparse = False)

Fx  = np.cos(x + 2*y)
Fy  = np.sin(x - 2*y)

F = [Fx, Fy]
h = [dx, dy]



print('plotting')
rows = 1
cols = 2
#plt.clf()
plt.figure(figsize=(cols*3.5,rows*3.5))
plt.minorticks_on()


#g = np.gradient(Fx,dx, axis=1)+np.gradient(Fy,dy, axis=0) # equivalent to our func
g = divergence(F,h)
ax = plt.subplot(rows,cols,1,aspect='equal',title='div numerical')
#im=plt.pcolormesh(x, y, g)
im = plt.pcolormesh(x, y, g, shading='nearest', cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('coolwarm'))
plt.quiver(x,y,Fx,Fy)
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
cbar = plt.colorbar(im, cax = cax,format='%.1f')


g = -np.sin(x+2*y) -2*np.cos(x-2*y)
ax = plt.subplot(rows,cols,2,aspect='equal',title='div analytical')
im=plt.pcolormesh(x, y, g)
im = plt.pcolormesh(x, y, g, shading='nearest', cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('coolwarm'))
plt.quiver(x,y,Fx,Fy)
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
cbar = plt.colorbar(im, cax = cax,format='%.1f')


plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig( 'divergence.png', format = 'png')
plt.show()
```

[image: numerical compare the analytical results]

Comment: Look at the maximum number in your colorbar, it's 0.2, but it should be 3! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67970477/compute-divergence-with-python/67971515#67971515

Comment: @henry You're right. Indeed, `numpy.gradient` colorbar range is a bit smaller than analytical results. People around me usually don't care about the color range. I would be happy if someone explains to me why. @_@

Comment: It’s because of the step size that no.gradient uses as a default (1) which does not corespondent to your step size. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67970477/compute-divergence-with-python/67971515#67971515

Comment: Or here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67971076/weird-behavior-of-np-gradient-with-increased-resolution

Comment: There's a <typo> and [missing comma] but this post cannot be edited. `np.gradient(f)` = df/dx, df/dy, df/dz[,] <+>...

Answer (score 2):

Based on @paul_chen answer, and with some additions for Matplotlib 3.3.0 (a shading param needs to be passed, and default colormap I guess has changed)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

NY = 20; ymin = -2.; ymax = 2.
dy = (ymax -ymin )/(NY-1.)
NX = NY
xmin = -2.; xmax = 2.
dx = (xmax -xmin)/(NX-1.)

def divergence(f):
    num_dims = len(f)
    return np.ufunc.reduce(np.add, [np.gradient(f[i], axis=i) for i in range(num_dims)])

y = np.array([ ymin + float(i)*dy for i in range(NY)])
x = np.array([ xmin + float(i)*dx for i in range(NX)])

x, y = np.meshgrid( x, y, indexing = 'ij', sparse = False)

Fx  = np.cos(x + 2*y)
Fy  = np.sin(x - 2*y)


F = [Fx, Fy]
g = divergence(F)

plt.pcolormesh(x, y, g, shading='nearest', cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('coolwarm'))
plt.colorbar()
plt.quiver(x,y,Fx,Fy)
plt.savefig( 'Div.png', format = 'png')
```

[image]

Comment: This is not entirely correct! np. gradient assumes a step of 1, but here the step is different. This is why you get maximum values that are around 0.6 and not 3. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67970477/compute-divergence-with-python/67971515#67971515

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the answer is that there is no native divergence function in numpy. Therefore, the *best* method for calculating divergence is to sum the components of the gradient vector i.e. *calculate* the divergence.

Answer (score 1):

The divergence as a built-in function is included in matlab, but not numpy. This is the sort of thing that it may perhaps be worthwhile to contribute to pylab, an effort to create a viable open-source alternative to matlab.

http://wiki.scipy.org/PyLab

Edit: Now called http://www.scipy.org/stackspec.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the answer by @Daniel is correct, especially when the input is in order `[Fx, Fy, Fz, ...]`.

### A simple test case

See the MATLAB code:

```matlab
a = [1 2 3;1 2 3; 1 2 3];
b = [[7 8 9] ;[1 5 8] ;[2 4 7]];
divergence(a,b)
```

which gives the result:

```
ans =

   -5.0000   -2.0000         0
   -1.5000   -1.0000         0
    2.0000         0         0
```

and Daniel's solution:

```py
def divergence(f):
    """
    Daniel's solution
    Computes the divergence of the vector field f, corresponding to dFx/dx + dFy/dy + ...
    :param f: List of ndarrays, where every item of the list is one dimension of the vector field
    :return: Single ndarray of the same shape as each of the items in f, which corresponds to a scalar field
    """
    num_dims = len(f)
    return np.ufunc.reduce(np.add, [np.gradient(f[i], axis=i) for i in range(num_dims)])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = np.array([[1, 2, 3]] * 3)
    b = np.array([[7, 8, 9], [1, 5, 8], [2, 4, 7]])
    div = divergence([a, b])
    print(div)
    pass
```

which gives:

```
[[1.  1.  1. ]
 [4.  3.5 3. ]
 [2.  2.5 3. ]]
```

### Explanation

The mistake of Daniel's solution is, in Numpy, **the x axis is the last axis instead of the first axis**. When using `np.gradient(x, axis=0)`, Numpy actually gives the gradient of *y direction* (when x is a 2d array).

### My solution

There is my solution based on Daniel's answer.

```
def divergence(f):
    """
    Computes the divergence of the vector field f, corresponding to dFx/dx + dFy/dy + ...
    :param f: List of ndarrays, where every item of the list is one dimension of the vector field
    :return: Single ndarray of the same shape as each of the items in f, which corresponds to a scalar field
    """
    num_dims = len(f)
    return np.ufunc.reduce(np.add, [np.gradient(f[num_dims - i - 1], axis=i) for i in range(num_dims)])
```

which gives the same result as MATLAB `divergence` in my test case.

Comment: In the Cartesian indexing convention, which MATLAB follows for meshgrid and NumPy follows for "xy" indexing in meshgrid, the x axis is simply the second axis (x and y are swappped). Thus Daniel's solution will work for [Fy, Fx, Fz, ...], where all Fn are in Cartesian indexing. Your "solution" reverses the order of everything and will not work as intended for dimension > 2, as it works for [..., Fz', Fy', Fx'], where the axes of each Fn' are in opposite order. For matrix indexing, Daniel's solution works as is.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the previous attempts to compute the divergence are wrong! Let me show you:

We have the following vector field F:

```
F(x) = cos(x+2y)
F(y) = sin(x-2y)
```

If we compute the divergence (using Mathematica):

```
Div[{Cos[x + 2*y], Sin[x - 2*y]}, {x, y}]
```

we get:

```
-2 Cos[x - 2 y] - Sin[x + 2 y]
```

which has a maximum value in the range of y [-1,2] and x [-2,2]:

```
N[Max[Table[-2 Cos[x - 2 y] - Sin[x + 2 y], {x, -2, 2 }, {y, -2, 2}]]] = 2.938
```

Using the divergence equation given here:

```
def divergence(f):
        num_dims = len(f)
        return np.ufunc.reduce(np.add, [np.gradient(f[i], axis=i) for i in range(num_dims)])
```

we get a maximum value of about `0.625`

## Correct divergence function: [Compute divergence with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67970477/compute-divergence-with-python/67971515#67971515)