# Calculate curl of a vector field in Python and plot it with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy

I need to calculate the curl of a vector field and plot it with matplotlib. A simple example of what I am looking for could be put like that:

How can I calculate and plot the curl of the vector field in the [quiver3d_demo.py](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/quiver3d_demo.html) in the matplotlib gallery?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a built-in function in numpy or scipy to calculate curl. If so you'll have to write that; in 3D the result will also be a vector field so matplotlib plots it just as in the example. [Similar question about divergence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435809/compute-divergence-of-vector-field-using-python)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Ok, I got it how to plot. Do you have any suggestions about a good way of writing the curl function?

Comment: Maybe using Sympy (http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/physics/vector/fields.html) could be useful. It has some built-in functionality for vector fields.

Comment: I see that Sympy has a `curl` function, and also handles plotting (using matplotlib as the back end), but I've never used it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [`sympy.curl()`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/physics/vector/api/fieldfunctions.html#curl) to calculate the curl of a vector field.

**Example**:

Suppose **F**(x,y,z) = y<sup>2</sup>z**i** - xy**j** + z<sup>2</sup>**k**, then:

- `y` would be `R[1]`, `x` is `R[0]` and `z` is `R[2]`
- the unit vectors **i**, **j**, **k** of the 3 axes, would be respectively `R.x`, `R.y`, `R.z`.

The code **to calculate the vector field curl** is:

```
from sympy.physics.vector import ReferenceFrame
from sympy.physics.vector import curl
R = ReferenceFrame('R')

F = R[1]**2 * R[2] * R.x - R[0]*R[1] * R.y + R[2]**2 * R.z

G = curl(F, R)
```

In that case G would be equal to `R_y**2*R.y + (-2*R_y*R_z - R_y)*R.z` or, in other words,
G = 0**i** + y<sup>2</sup>**j** + (-2yz-y)**k**.

**To plot it** you need to convert the above result into 3 separate functions; u,v,w.

(example below adapted from [this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/quiver3d_demo.html) matplotlib example):

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

x, y, z = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-0.8, 1, 0.2),
                      np.arange(-0.8, 1, 0.2),
                      np.arange(-0.8, 1, 0.8))

u = 0
v = y**2
w = -2*y*z - y

ax.quiver(x, y, z, u, v, w, length=0.1)

plt.show()
```

And the final result is this:

[image]

Comment: Please explain the downvotes. I'd love to fix any mistakes.

Answer (score 5):

To calculate the curl of a vector function you can also use [numdifftools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Numdifftools) for automatic numerical differentiation without a detour through symbolic differentiation.  Numdifftools doesn't provide a `curl()` function, but it does compute the Jacobian matrix of a vector valued function of one or more variables, and this provides the derivatives of all components of a vector field with respect to all of the variables; this is all that's necessary for the calculation of the curl.

```
import import scipy as sp
import numdifftools as nd

def h(x):
    return sp.array([3*x[0]**2,4*x[1]*x[2]**3, 2*x[0]])

def curl(f,x):
    jac = nd.Jacobian(f)(x)
    return sp.array([jac[2,1]-jac[1,2],jac[0,2]-jac[2,0],jac[1,0]-jac[0,1]])

x = sp.array([1,2,3)]
curl(h,x)
```

This returns the value of the curl at `x`: `array([-216.,   -2.,    0.])`
Plotting is as suggested above.

Comment: I prefer this solution to the accepted answer, as it's infrequent that I deal with analytical vector fields. However, it is a bit inefficient as the curl does not use the trace of the Jacobian (thus 1/3 of the work in nd.Jacobian is not used here). Do you think it would be faster to compute the off-diagonal elements of the Jacobian independently using nd.directionaldiff()? Or do you think the additional python code overhead would make it not worth it?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a Python code that is based on an Octave / Matlab [implementation](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/octave-Faddeeva/scripts/general/curl.m),

```
import numpy as np

def curl(x,y,z,u,v,w):
    dx = x[0,:,0]
    dy = y[:,0,0]
    dz = z[0,0,:]

    dummy, dFx_dy, dFx_dz = np.gradient (u, dx, dy, dz, axis=[1,0,2])
    dFy_dx, dummy, dFy_dz = np.gradient (v, dx, dy, dz, axis=[1,0,2])
    dFz_dx, dFz_dy, dummy = np.gradient (w, dx, dy, dz, axis=[1,0,2])

    rot_x = dFz_dy - dFy_dz
    rot_y = dFx_dz - dFz_dx
    rot_z = dFy_dx - dFx_dy

    l = np.sqrt(np.power(u,2.0) + np.power(v,2.0) + np.power(w,2.0));

    m1 = np.multiply(rot_x,u)
    m2 = np.multiply(rot_y,v)
    m3 = np.multiply(rot_z,w)

    tmp1 = (m1 + m2 + m3)
    tmp2 = np.multiply(l,2.0)

    av = np.divide(tmp1, tmp2)

    return rot_x, rot_y, rot_z, av
```

Comment: What is `av`? The average?