# How to obtain the components of curl?

Tags: python, math, sympy

[Calculate curl of a vector field in Python and plot it with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378676/calculate-curl-of-a-vector-field-in-python-and-plot-it-with-matplotlib)

In the first answer,

```
from sympy.physics.vector import ReferenceFrame
from sympy.physics.vector import curl
R = ReferenceFrame('R')
F = R[1]**2 * R[2] * R.x - R[0]*R[1] * R.y + R[2]**2 * R.z
G = curl(F, R)
```

Now he prints G, obtains the expressions for the components of the curl field, manually and assigns them as

```
u = 0
v = y**2
w = -2*y*z - y
```

How to obtain, u,v,w directly from G, instead how manually printing and assigning?
What is G? Can we convert it into a string ?
I don't want to plot, I just want the expressions for the components of the curl.

Comment: The link/answer uses `sympy`.  If that's what you are using as well, fix the tags.  And expand on your code so we have a clearer idea of the context and variables.

Comment: @hpaulj I've edited the question, kindly take a look

Comment: The curl docs - https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/physics/vector/api/fieldfunctions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate further on @smichr 's answer:

```
from sympy.abc import x, y, z
print(list(G.args[0][0].subs([(R[0], x), (R[1], y), (R[2], z)])))
```

Results in

```
[0, y**2, -2*y*z - y]
```

And

```
u, v, w = list(G.args[0][0].subs([(R[0], x), (R[1], y), (R[2], z)]))
```

gets everything in the same form as your question.

PS:
`G.args` gives the [top-level arguments](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/manipulation.html#args) of G. `print(G.args)`can be used to investigate how it is built up. In SymPy [`srepr()`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/manipulation.html) can help to figure out the internal representation of symbols.

PPS: about your question in the comments:

```
R = ReferenceFrame('R')
P = y**2 *z
Q =- x*y
R = z**2
H = P* R.x +Q * R.y + RR* R.z
```

Does not work because `R = z**2` erases `R = ReferenceFrame('R')`. You should use different variable names.

Comment: I'm new to python, please bare with me. Can you please explain what is G? what does G.args[0][0] do?

Comment: `from sympy.abc import x, y, z
P=y**2 * z
Q=- x*y
R=z**2
R = ReferenceFrame('R')
H =  P* R.x +Q * R.y + R * R.z
F=H.subs([(x, R[0]), (y, R[1]), (z, R[2])])
print(F)
G = curl(F, R)  
print(list(G.args[0][0].subs([(R[0], x), (R[1], y), (R[2], z)])))`
This throws up an error, how to substitute P,Q,R in F?

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
>>> list(G.args[0][0])
[0, R_y**2, -2*R_y*R_z - R_y]
```

Or, using the `varlist` attribute of R, we can replace `R_x` with `x`, etc..., as

```
>>> u,v,w = G.args[0][0].subs(dict(zip(R.varlist, var('x:z'))))
>>> u, v, w
(0, y**2, -2*y*z - y)
```

Comment: I'm new to python, please bare with me. Can you please explain what is G? what does G.args[0][0] do?