# matplotlib streamline with the area of divergence and convergence

Tags: matplotlib

I ploted streamlines using the u and v. How do i determine whether divergence or convergence was occurring and plot those shapes in same figure with matplotlib?

[streamline test, red is divergence and blue is convergence.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSqNk.png)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can colour streamlines in any way you want, so get whatever form of [divergence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435809/compute-divergence-of-vector-field-using-python) you want and use that,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Y, X = np.mgrid[-3:3:100j, -3:3:100j]
U = -1 - X**2 + Y
V = 1 + X - Y**2
divUV = reduce(np.add,np.gradient(U)) + reduce(np.add,np.gradient(V))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
strm = ax.streamplot(X, Y, U, V, color=divUV, cmap=plt.cm.RdBu)
fig.colorbar(strm.lines)

plt.show()
```

Not sure the divergence looks right here but you get the idea. Alternatively, you could overlay a colormesh with transparency,

```
cm = ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, divU, cmap=plt.cm.RdBu, alpha=0.4)
fig.colorbar(cm)
```

Comment: yeah, great. This is a good alternative, but the divergence does not looks perfect. Probably shouldn't ask such a question here, the most important thing is to understand how to calculate the divergence and convergence in meteological. Thanks a lot.