# Calculate Divergence of Velocity Field (3D) in Python

Tags: python, vector, field, physics, fluid-dynamics

I am trying to calculate the divergence of a 3D velocity field in a multi-phase flow setting (with solids immersed in a fluid). If we assume `u`,`v`,`w` to be the three velocity components (each a `n x n x n`) 3D numpy array, here is the function I have for calculating divergence:

```
def calc_divergence_velocity(df,h=0.025):
    """        
        @param df: A dataframe with the entire vector field with columns [x,y,z,u,v,w] with 
                   x,y,z indicating the 3D coordinates of each point in the field and u,v,w
                   the velocities in the x,y,z directions respectively.  
        @param h: This is the dimension of a single side of the 3D (uniform) grid. Used 
                  as input to numpy.gradient() function.
    """

    """
        Reshape dataframe columns to get 3D numpy arrays (dim = 80) so each u,v,w is a 
        80x80x80 ndarray.
    """ 
   
    u = df['u'].values.reshape((dim,dim,dim))
    v = df['v'].values.reshape((dim,dim,dim))
    w = df['w'].values.reshape((dim,dim,dim))
    
    #Supply x,y,z coordinates appropriately.
    
    #Note: Only a scalar `h` has been supplied to np.gradient because
    #the type of grid we are dealing with is a uniform grid with each
    #grid cell having the same dimensions in x,y,z directions.

    u_grad = np.gradient(u,h,axis=0)   #central diff. du_dx
    v_grad = np.gradient(v,h,axis=1)   #central diff. dv_dy
    w_grad = np.gradient(w,h,axis=2)   #central diff. dw_dz
    
    """
        The `mask` column in the dataframe is a binary column indicating the locations
        in the field where we are interested in measuring divergence.
        The problem I am looking at is multi-phase flow with solid particles and a fluid
        hence we are only interested in the fluid locations.
    """
    sdf = df['mask'].values.reshape((dim,dim,dim))  
    

    div = (u_grad*sdf) + (v_grad*sdf) + (w_grad*sdf)

    return div
```

The problem I'm having is that the divergence values that I am seeing are far too high.
For example the image below showcases, a distribution with values between [-350,350] whereas most values should technically be close to zero and somewhere between [20,-20] in my case. This tells me I'm calculating the divergence incorrectly and I would like some pointers as to how to correct the above function to calculate the divergence appropriately. As far as I can tell (please correct me if I'm wrong), I think have done something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43759790/4077004) upvoted SO response. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: When computing the derivatives, you should be consistent with the solver that has produced this flow field: Is it a finite-volume solver? finite-difference? What's the order? Only this way you can match the free-divergence solver accuracy - Try to use the same numerical method.

Comment: I believe it is a finite volume solver used to produce the original flow field. However I am not looking to exactly match the divergence free flow field, just trying to approximately get some semblance of similarity in terms of the distribution of divergence. However I see very high values (>100, <-100) which should never happen. I almost wonder if the ‘h’ scalar value that I supply to numpy gradient is required as I am dealing with a uniform  grid ? If I don’t use the ‘h’ value then the scales of the divergence values seem okay.

Comment: Of course `h`, which is the grid spacing, is an important factor here and it is indeed required for `numpy.gradient`. You should use whatever was used in the solver - in a uniform grid one can set the spacing to any value desired, although is normally set to 1 for scaling purposes and it's the default value for `numpy.gradient`. Just double-check what is the spacing used in the simulation and use it here.