# Compute divergence with python

Tags: python, matplotlib, vector

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435809/compute-divergence-of-vector-field-using-python/21134289) answer, the divergence of a numeric vector field can be computed as such:

```
def divergence(f):
    num_dims = len(f)
    return np.ufunc.reduce(np.add, [np.gradient(f[i], axis=i) for i in range(num_dims)])
```

However, I have noticed that the output seems to depend a lot on the grid resolution, so there seems to be something wrong!

If I look at an example:

We have the following vector field F:

```
F(x) = cos(x+2y)
F(y) = sin(x-2y)
```

If we compute the divergence (using Mathematica):

```
Div[{Cos[x + 2*y], Sin[x - 2*y]}, {x, y}]
```

we get:

```
-2 Cos[x - 2 y] - Sin[x + 2 y]
```

which has a maximum value in the range of y [-2,2] and x [-2,2]:

```
N[Max[Table[-2 Cos[x - 2 y] - Sin[x + 2 y], {x, -2, 2 }, {y, -2, 2}]]] = 2.938
```

Using the divergence equation given here, we get the following plot, for max value vs. resolution (NxN: number of values in x and y-direction). None of these are even close to 3.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Boundaries
ymin = -2.; ymax = 2.
xmin = -2.; xmax = 2.
# Number of points (NxN)
N = 20

# Divergence function
def divergence(f):
    num_dims = len(f)
    return np.ufunc.reduce(np.add, [np.gradient(f[i], axis=i) for i in range(num_dims)])

# Create Meshgrid
x = np.linspace(xmin,xmax, N)
y = np.linspace(ymin,ymax, N)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)


# Define 2D Vector Field
Fx  = np.cos(xx + 2*yy)
Fy  = np.sin(xx - 2*yy)

F = np.array([Fx, Fy])
# Compute Divergence
g = divergence(F)

print("Max: ", np.max(g.flatten()))

plt.imshow(g)
plt.colorbar()
```

Edit:
To create the plot:

```
# %%
a = []
for N in range(20,100):
    # Number of points (NxN)
    # = 20
    # Boundaries
    ymin = -2.; ymax = 2.
    xmin = -2.; xmax = 2.
    
    
    # Deivergence function
    def divergence(f):
        num_dims = len(f)
        return np.ufunc.reduce(np.add, [np.gradient(f[i], axis=i) for i in range(num_dims)])
    
  
    
    # Create Meshgrid
    x = np.linspace(xmin,xmax, N)
    y = np.linspace(ymin,ymax, N)
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    
    
    # Define 2D Vector Field
    Fx  = np.cos(xx + 2*yy)
    Fy  = np.sin(xx - 2*yy)
    
    F = np.array([Fx, Fy])
    # Compute Divergence
    g = divergence(F)
    
    print("Max: ", np.max(g.flatten()))
    a.append(np.max(g.flatten()))
plt.plot(a)
```

Answer (score 3):

I realized what the issue was with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67971076/weird-behavior-of-np-gradient-with-increased-resolution/67971277#67971277). The default spacing assumed between two consecutive values in numpy.gradient() is 1. It needs to be changed if there is a different grid.

Hence the divergence function needs to be adapted as such:

## Divergence function

```
def divergence(f,sp):
    """ Computes divergence of vector field 
    f: array -> vector field components [Fx,Fy,Fz,...]
    sp: array -> spacing between points in respecitve directions [spx, spy,spz,...]
    """
    num_dims = len(f)
    return np.ufunc.reduce(np.add, [np.gradient(f[i], sp[i], axis=i) for i in range(num_dims)])
```

## Example

```
a = []
for N in range(20,100):
    # Number of points (NxN)
    # = 20
    # Boundaries
    ymin = -2.; ymax = 2.
    xmin = -2.; xmax = 2.
    
    
    # Divergence function
    def divergence(f,sp):
        num_dims = len(f)
        return np.ufunc.reduce(np.add, [np.gradient(f[i], sp[i], axis=i) for i in range(num_dims)])

    
    # Create Meshgrid
    x = np.linspace(xmin,xmax, N)
    y = np.linspace(ymin,ymax, N)
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    
    
    # Define 2D Vector Field
    Fx  = np.cos(xx + 2*yy)
    Fy  = np.sin(xx - 2*yy)
    
    F = np.array([Fx, Fy])
    # Compute Divergence
    sp_x = np.diff(x)[0]
    sp_y = np.diff(y)[0]
    sp = [sp_x, sp_y]
    g = divergence(F, sp)
    
    print("Max: ", np.max(g.flatten()))
    a.append(np.max(g.flatten()))
plt.plot(a)
```

We can see that with increasing resolution, the maximum of the divergence really tends to 3.

[image]