# Numerical Divergence of a Tensor Field in Spherical Coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, numerical-methods

I want to calculate the divergence of a rank-2 tensor field ($$\nabla \cdot T = \partial_i T_{ij}$$) defined on the surface of a sphere. As an example, let the field be given as follows :

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)

LAT = 100
LONG = 100

tensor_field = np.array([np.random.rand(LAT,LONG) for i in range(9)])
```

here, each one of the 9 entries corresponds to one component in spherical coordinates of the rank-2 tensor.

If it were a rank-1 tensor field (a vector field), I could brute force my way by manually converting each component to Cartesian basis, and calculate the divergence as done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67970477/compute-divergence-with-python?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Is there a simpler way for higher rank tensor fields?

Comment: Divergence with respect to which component? - presumably the first in a rank-2 tensor. For each collection of the second (and higher) indices take the divergence of a vector. BTW, there are better ways of taking the divergence in spherical polars than converting to cartesian basis - see, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates

Comment: 1. Yes, it is wrt the first index. I have altered the question to reflect that
2. Thanks for the suggestion! I felt converting to Cartesian basis and using the fact that the divergence of a vector is a scalar would be easier than custom writing a function for doing it directly with spherical components